# Evaluation of the multiple integral

Tags: co.combinatorics, real-analysis

Would you give me any suggestions or comments on evaluating the following $n$-dimensional 
integral? $$ \int_{[0,t]^n} h(x) dx  $$

where 
$ x=(x_1 ,x_2 , \cdots, x_n ), h(x)= \prod_{k=1}^n min( \bar{x}_k), \bar{x}_k =\{x_1,x_2, \cdots,x_n \} - \{x_k \}$

Comment: where does this integral arise?

Comment: If $h(x)=min \{x_1,x_2,\cdots, x_n \}$, I can easily handle it. But I wonder that there is(are) any nice ways to get the value of the problem given above.

Comment: I don't get it anywhere from. I just consider it for fun.

Comment: The integrand is symmetric, so the value of the integral on $I^n$ is $n!$ times the value of the integral of $x_2 x_1^{n-1}$ on the simplex $\{0<x_1<x_2<\dots<x_n<1\}$, that you can easily compute by iterate integration.  Should be $\frac{1}{2n\choose n+1}$.

Comment: Thanks, Pietro. How about the case $h(x)=min(x_1,x_2) min(x_2,x_3) \cdots min(x_{n-1},x_n) min(x_n,x_1)$ ?

Comment: In this case I'd try writing a recurrence relation for the integrals in terms of  $H_n(t):=\int_{I^n} \min(x_1,x_2)\min(x_2,x_3)⋯\min(x_{n−1},x_n)\min(x_n,t)dx$.

Comment: I had found the similar question on the cycle type in the paper Noam Elkies!!

Comment: ???????????????

Answer (score 4):

This is $\mathbb E (X_1^{n-1} X_2) $ where $ X_i $ is the $ i $ th order statistic of a sample from the uniform distribution on $[0, t] $.
To evaluate it can try using the joint pdf of these order statistics, given at
http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_statistic